# How can I add a ZWrite pass to a transparent shader graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shaderlab

I have been trying to achieve [this effect from Tim-C](https://forum.unity.com/threads/transparent-depth-shader-good-for-ghosts.149511/) (which all seems to be outdated, even the fixes posted in the comments) with ShaderGraph (Unity 2019.3.0f3), but as far as I know you can't do that within ShaderGraph, so after looking at [this page on the ShaderLab documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) I came up with the following shaders that use a shader graph I made.

Using this shader displays the shader graph completely fine:

```
Shader "Custom/BlockPreview_ZWrite"
{
    Properties
    {
        //Has the same name as 'Reference' in shader graph.
        PreviewColor("Hologram Color", Color) = (0.90, 0.90, 0.90, 0.20)
    }

    SubShader
    {

        Tags {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"
        }

        UsePass "Shader Graphs/BlockPreview_Graph/Pass"

    }

}
```

So I tried adding a ZWrite pass, but this shader will just display nothing at all (but the outline in the scene view still works like it's there):

```
Shader "Unlit/BlockPreviewZ"
{
    Properties
    {
        //Has the same name as 'Reference' in shader graph.
        PreviewColor("Hologram Color", Color) = (0.90, 0.90, 0.90, 0.20)
    }

    SubShader
    {

        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"
        }

        Pass                                                                                           //
        {                                                                                              //
            ZWrite On                                                                                  //
            ColorMask 0   //Commenting out this line will just display a solid white object.           //
        }                                                                                              //

        UsePass "Shader Graphs/BlockPreview_Graph/Pass"

    }

}
```

Other than what I've wrote here, I have very little ShaderLab experience or knowledge, so what can I do to make the `UsePass` work with the `ZWrite` pass I need to add?

Comment: Thank you for the ColorMask 0 thing !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, LWRP/URP using only the first pass is a “feature”. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/lwrp-only-first-pass-gets-rendered-when-using-multi-pass-shaders

I will probably get around this by using two rendered meshes layered over each other. One will do the ZWrite (first), and the other will just be the normal shader graph.

**Update** This works:
[image: Screenshot of the 'Materials' array of the Mesh Renderer.]